# jQuery copy data returned from $.post into page

Tags: jquery

I am using $.post to post a form to the server.  The server then returns a html page. I want to replace the current page content with what is returned from the server.  How would I do this using jquery?

code so far:

```
$('.autosave').click(function(){
    var url = 'post form url';

    $postData = $('#page-form').serialize();

    $.post(url, $postData, function(data){
             PAGE SOURCE = data
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: what's the purpose of changing whole html, Isn't it the same to redirect page to desired page generated by you server code?

Comment: Why on earth would you do this? Use a normal form. The _entire point_ of XmlHttpRequest is to allow you to do _not this_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't replace the entire page's contents but rather a container. Regardless, the code is:

```
$.post(url, $postData, function(response)
{
     // this works for any valid css selector, so "body" 
     // and ".class_name" works too
     $('#container').html(response);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

At the simplest level...

`$('body').html(data);`

Assuming the response is exactly what you want to replace with, and you want to replace everything in the document body.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('.autosave').click(function(){
    $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');    
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the content with a given HTML you can uses .replaceWith()

Assuming your div is with class "myContent",

```
$(".myContent").replaceWith(data);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can replace html elements in your page but not the whole html. Imagine if you reinstall your OS on the fly.</strike>

Btw if you want to insert your data into `<div id="item">`, you can do this:

```
$.post(url, $postData, function(data){
    $('#item').html(data);
});
```

Comment: sure you can. `$('html').html(data)` will do that

Comment: @Jules if you can do something doesn't mean you could do that. :)

Comment: apparently i'm not very familiar with the difference between could and can :) i'm just saying you can. while you say 'you can replace elements but [you can] not [replace] the whole html'. so saying you can not, would that be the same as you could?

Comment: cool, i'm still confused about the difference between could and can though. but maybe i'd better head over to http://english.stackexchange.com for that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can actualy use `$("html").load(url+"?"+$postData);`
instead of

```
$.post(url, $postData, function(data){
         $("html").html(data);
});
```

this will also change your page title and other content inside your `head` tags. be aware though that your loaded `script` tags wont be accessible in DOM afterwards